# Using javax.ws.rs.* to create a REST Client, but POST request doesn't work properly

Tags: java, rest, curl, jax-rs

I try to make a POST Call to a Webservice that is a gateway to other Webservices (adding authentication token and logging).

My gateway service runs and I could create a valid post request by the following CURL Statement (Status = 200):

```
 curl -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorization-service-backend/gateway" -H "accept: text/html" -H "UniqueUserId: 123" -H "DestinationUrl: http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorization-service-backend/healthCheck" -H "HttpMessage: GET"
```

But when I call the service inside my testcase, I get HTTP 415 for a wrong mediatype. Here comes the code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/authorization-service-backend/gateway");

MultivaluedMap<String, Object> callHeaders =
        new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
callHeaders.add("accept","text/html");
callHeaders.add("UniqueUserId", "user123");
callHeaders.add("DestinationUrl", "http://localhost:8080/authorization-service-backend/healthCheck");
callHeaders.add("HttpMessage", "GET");
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
        .headers(callHeaders);
Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.text(4000));
int statusCode = response.getStatus();
```

Here is the openapi specification:

```
paths:
  /gateway:
    post:
      operationId: gateway
      parameters:
      - name: UniqueUserId
        in: header
        style: simple
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: DestinationUrl
        in: header
        style: simple
        schema:
          type: string
      - name: HttpMessage
        in: header
        style: simple
        schema:
          type: string
      responses:
        default:
          description: Default Response.
          content:
            text/html:
              schema:
                type: object
```

Comment: In the cURL request you aren't sending an entity in the body. But in the JAX-RS request you are, with a content-type of text/plain. 415 means that the content-type is not acceptable. You can try to set a null body or use a different content-type.

Comment: @Paul Samsotha

How can I set a null body?

Is that the parameter of the post-method? invocationBuilder.post(Entity.text(4000));

I'm fairly new to that topic.

And I set the mediatype itwo times, are they redundant? I expected that this is the media type that I request from the server.

Comment: I just tested with your cURL request, and without explicitly setting the content-type header and having no body, it defaults to setting the content-type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. If you want to do the same, you can try to use Entity.entity("", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).